# Import cv2 Error in google cloud virtual machine

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, opencv

I am currently trying to run a python script on a GCE virtual machine. However, I keep getting an error when using 'import cv2':

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "train.py", line 12, in <module> from deeplab.datasets import DataSetTrain, DataSetVal

File "/jet/prs/workspace/FYP-Project/Pytorch-Deeplab-master/deeplab/datasets.py", line 10, in <module>

import cv2

File "/jet/prs/workspace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>

from .cv2 import *

ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The problem with this is that I have checked that the directory the file being referenced is present. I have installed and reinstalled cv2, however nothing seems to be working. None of the other modules that i installed using pip have this issue, it seems to only occur with cv2.

Comment: can you read this doc https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0` if this doesn't work, maybe the system allocated to you might be 32 bits or the tools might be 32 bit in which case try `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386`

Comment: thanks for the advice i have already tried sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386 however it does not seem to work. Thanks for the help though.